# Is the answer wrong on the Norton equivalent from E4U, or is my analysis wrong?

Tags: norton

[Original question](https://www.electrical4u.com/norton-theorem-norton-equivalent-current-and-resistance/#:%7E:text=Norton%20equivalent%20circuit%20is%20a,of%20a%20Thevenin%20voltage%20source.)

I have taken screenshot of the question here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my analysis:

[image]

$$
R_{parallel} = \frac{5 \times 35} {5 + 35}
=
\frac{35} {8}
$$

$$
I = \frac{60} {5+R_{parallel}} = \frac{32} {5}
$$

$$
I_1 = I \frac{5} {5 + R_{parallel}}
= 0.8 A
$$

[image]

$$
R_{parallel}
= \frac{5 \times 5} {5+5}
=2.5
$$

$$
I_2
=
I \frac{20}{20 + R_{parallel} + 15}
=
2 \frac{20}{20 + 2.5 + 15}
=
\frac{16}{15}
$$

$$
I_{N} = I_{AB}
= I_1 + I_2
= \frac{28} {15}
\approx
1.8667 A
$$

Is my analysis right?

Comment: I tend to prefer KCL for analysis. But I see the site using KVL. One way to very quickly visualize this circuit is to realize that the current source has infinite impedance and that the voltage source has zero impedance. So the equivalent resistance is 20+5||5+15=37.5 Ohms. Takes only a second to see it. The voltage at the terminals will be half the 60 V (because of the two 5 Ohm resistors dividing it in half) + the voltage developed across the 20 Ohm resistor by the 2A source -- so 30V + 40V = 70 V. That's it. It's not rocket science! No KCL or KVL need apply.

Comment: @jonk It's not Thevenin, although the resistor is the same for both Thevenin and Norton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn0hmw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

And we also know that \$\text{V}_0-\text{V}_3=\text{V}_\text{i}\$.

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_5}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I0 + I2 + I3, I4 == I0 + I3, I1 == I2 + I4, 
   I1 == (V0 - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1 - V3)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, 
   I4 == (0 - V3)/R4, I4 == (V2 - 0)/R5, V0 - V3 == Vi}, {I1, I2, I3, 
   I4, V0, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (I0 R2 R3 + (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I2 -> (-I0 R1 R3 + (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I3 -> (-I0 (R2 (R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R4 + R5)) + R2 Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I4 -> (I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V0 -> (-I0 (R1 + R2) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R5) Vi + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V1 -> (-I0 R3 (R2 R4 + R1 (R2 + R4)) + R2 (R3 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V2 -> (R5 (I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi))/(
   R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V3 -> -((R4 (I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi))/(
    R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)))}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\text{I}_0\text{R}_3+\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_4\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{I}_0\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R5 (I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi))/(
  R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), R5 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=I0 R3 + (R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi)/(
  R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5)), R5 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(I0 (R1 + R2) R3 + R2 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))/(R1 + R2)
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=70\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{28}{15}\approx1.86667\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{75}{2}=37.5\space\Omega\tag9$$

Comment: It's not Thevenin. And it's Norton Instead.